# Keep requested/entered url with add_rewrite_rule

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I've got url-rewriting partially working. I have this rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^somepage/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?p=27&target=$matches[1]&arrival=$matches[2]&departure=$matches[3]','top');
```

When I request a page like this:

```
http://yourpage.com/wp/somepage/florida/02-03-2012/03-03-2012/
```

The Visitor gets redirected to:

```
http://yourpage.com/wp/somepage/
```

But I'd like to keep the additional parameters of the original url. 
How can I achieve this?

And I noticed something else. When I generate a link like above from a form via JavaScript I get "page not found" although the url is correct. Now when I refresh that same page I get redirected to the page mentioned above. Why isn't it working on the first try?

I'd appreciate any help.

Kind regards,
Denyo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. Instead of using this rewrite rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^somepage/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?p=27&target=$matches[1]&arrival=$matches[2]&departure=$matches[3]','top');
```

I now use this one:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^somepage/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=somepage&target=$matches[1]&arrival=$matches[2]&departure=$matches[3]','top');
```

And now everything works like I wanted it to. Obviously using the page id instead of the page name was the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had this problem for a month and could not find the answer !